# Azure CosmosDB Contains method does not working

Tags: c#, linq, azure, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I'm not sure but I think that I found a bug in Azure Cosmos DB. Here is my situation. I have the following JSON

```
{
    "id": "token",
    "User": {
        "UserToken": "token",
        "Email": "email@email.com"
    },
    "_ts": 1521728825
}
```

And I wrote a following query using LINQ:

```
await _dbClient.Where<UserDocument>(_collectionUri,feedOptions,  
        d => d.User.UserToken == searchString
             || d.User.Email.Contains(searchString))                        
    .OrderByDescending(d => d.Timestamp)
    .AsDocumentQuery().ToListAsync())
```

When I run it with `searchString=="token"` it will return an empty list, so I decide to modify the query:

```
await _dbClient.Where<UserDocument>(_collectionUri,feedOptions,  
        d => d.User.UserToken == searchString)                        
    .OrderByDescending(d => d.Timestamp)
    .AsDocumentQuery().ToListAsync())
```

Magically it started working. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? or maby there is an issue with `CONTAINS` method in CosmosDB??

Comment: Interesting fact is that when I add the order by clause to my query, I consistently get zero results back.

Comment: Is `UserToken` indexed? And if so, is your index being Consistent or Lazy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a bug. It has to do with your collection's Indexing policy.

I don't know what your indexing policy currently looks like but when an exact match works and a partial match doesn't, on a string, then it's safe to say that you are using a `Hash` index for your Strings.

When using hash, only equality checks will return values. You will need to change your string index to `Range` and precision `-1` to partially match strings.

You can find your index settings under the `Scale & Settings` section of the Data explorer.

If your indexing policy looks like this:

[image]

Then changing it to this:

[image]

Should work.

You can however limit this even more and only index the `/User/Email/?` as a `Range` and keep the rest as Hashes.

You can also override this behaviour by providing a `FeedOptions` object with the value `EnableScanInQuery` set to `true`. However I've got mixed results with this so I'd go with the index change.

I highly recommend you talk a look at the indexing documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies). There is also a great video explaining more about it.

Comment: You've right. I've invalid indexing policy as you mention and OrderBy destroys my query

Comment: Yeah ordering on the system defined `_ts` field is tricky. Also OrderBy won't work on `Hash` fields.